# One schema value is missing out

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am registering company details and also trying to verify *email id* of admin of that company to *true*.

All of the details is showing up on callback json except one ie; `verified`

**Here is my schema details:-**

```
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty.",
                required: false
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String,
                },              
    address :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Address can't be empty.",
                },
    contactDetails : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company contact number can't be empty.",
                },
    admins:     {
                        email :     {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Email can't be empty.",
                                    unique: true
                                    },
                        password:   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Password name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        firstName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "First name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        lastName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Last name can't be empty."
                                    },  
                        phoneNumber :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                                    },
                        designation :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Designation can't be empty."
                                    },          
                        verified:   { 
                                    type: Boolean, 
                                    default: false 
                                    },
                        role: String,
                        emailResetTokenn: String,
                        emailExpires: Date,
                        saltSecret: String,//this is user for encryption and decryption of password 
                        users:[]    
    }           
});
```

**In controller I am doing :-**

```
module.exports.registerAdmin = (req, res, next) =>{ 

    var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.address = req.body.address;
    admin.contactDetails  = req.body.contactDetails;
    admin.admins = {
                  email : req.body.email,
                  password: req.body.password, 
                  firstName : req.body.firstName, 
                  lastName : req.body.lastName,
                  phoneNumber : req.body.phoneNumber,
                  designation : req.body.designation,
                  role : "admin",
                  users: []
    };
```

When I am running my route api ,  the `verified` detail is not showing up as `verified : false`

**result:-**

```
{
    "admins": {
        "email": "losefivex@mrmail.info",
        "password": "$2a$10$pgkFZAfGwHkJ2e88/d2gUeWtjVdinxGmYGx5Euh69kgH95nCIUcNa",
        "firstName": "hdsdsds",
        "lastName": "Ghodsdsdsh",
        "phoneNumber": "4544343",
        "designation": "Software Engineer",
        "role": "admin",
        "users": [],
        "emailResetTokenn": "c833599ab72255a957007b42ca1cb8fddd566d7474b8b2b92bc08252f60184fa",
        "emailExpires": "2019-05-21T18:05:46.095Z",
        "saltSecret": "$2a$10$pgkFZAfGwHkJ2e88/d2gUe"
    },
    "_id": "5ce3e99a896e8c3ff5665702",
    "companyName": "Meta",
    "address": "AUS",
    "contactDetails": "54534454",
    "companyID": "675521",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Why it is  missing out ?

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not quite sure why the value is not being set, but you if you do not create the Admin Document and then edit it before saving, but create the admin object and pass it to the new Admin() constructor afterwards, the defaults are being set:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const STACKOVERFLOW_ISSUE = `56238095`;
const connectionString = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${ STACKOVERFLOW_ISSUE }`;
const { Schema, SchemaTypes } = mongoose;

run()
    .then(() => console.log('done'))
    .catch(error => console.error(error.stack));

async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect(connectionString);
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();



    const AdminSchema = new Schema({
        test: String,
        admins: {
            email: String,
            verified: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            }
        }
    });

    const Admin = mongoose.model('admins', AdminSchema);

    /* THE INTERESTING PART BELOW*/
    const newAdmin = {
      test: 'someString',
      admins: {
        email: 'someEmail'
      }
    }
    // creating testObject by passing the blueprint to it
    const test1 = new Admin(newAdmin);
    await test1.save();

    process.exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I am not editing value before saving. I am doing the same on other schema but don't know what happened over here

Comment: When I said "editing" I meant that you FIRST call the constructor and then set the properties instead of first creating an object of properties and then calling the constructor with it. My suggestion why it worked somewhere else is because it was not a nested value? Since admins is not required, it could be empty and therefor mongoose doesn't set the defaults on creation. You could also try to see if you can find a solution using .markModified()

Comment: Yes you are right. It was not a nested value on other model. Thanks for explaining. I really need this solution to be working as it depends on my login system. So what changes i must do in my controller so that `admins` will be required ?

Comment: You can try wrapping your current schema definition of admins.admins in a .type definition so that you can also set it to required:true. This might work: admin.admins: {type: {email: req.body.email ...}, required: true}. Still, what stops you from quickly refactoring the code to call the constructor with the "blueprint"-object?